# PowerBI Relationship

Tags: powerbi

I have a PowerBI Report that contains information from both an ERP and a CRM, I am trying to create a drill through that will allow users to drill through ERP data to show CRM data. I am having issues trying to structure my table relationships, I think I will need a helper table somewhere. Appreciate any thoughts you may have.

[image: Sample Tables]

Comment: I think  CustomerBillCode cannot be a unique/related key in both system. You will either need to have AccountID in ERP or CustomerAccCode in CRM and then you can link them otherwise I do not see primary/unique key to relate them.

Answer (score 1):

in PowerBI you can now use Many:Many relationship, in your case it should be single direction with `CRM Accounts` filtering `ERP Customers`. See more here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-many-to-many-relationships
and here:
https://www.sqlbi.com/tv/different-types-of-many-to-many-relationships-in-power-bi/

it's effectively the same as creating a helper table as explained in the second link